# Screen Suddenly Going to Screensaver

Tags: power-management, screen

In Ubuntu 19.10, I do not have the screen saver enabled and indeed it hasn’t been coming on until today when it suddenly started locking after only about thirty seconds, requiring my password to log back in. I checked the power and screen settings and they are the same as they have been with nothing I can find to account for it. Between when it wasn’t doing it and now, there were no system updates either and it just started doing it out of the blue. Any ideas as to what might have happened and how to stop it?

Comment: I’ve looked everywhere but nothing seems to be enabled to account for this.  Even with the screensaver and power management disabled, the screen still goes blank after only about thirty seconds although it is no longer immediately locking until closer to an hour.